# google play RTDN only working with test notifications

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play

I have developed a Unity app which uses Unity IAP, I published it in the Google Play Store and it's now currently in production and working. The app itself manages the purchase trough Unity IAP, and when the purchase is completed, it sends to my server the Google Receipt, which gets then sent and verified via Google API to activate the purchase on my server.

Everything is fine so far.

Now, I have configured a Pub/Sub by setting up a Topic Name and a Subscriber that pushes messages to a custom url on my server, and then I added the "Topic name" in the "Monetisation setup" -> "Google Play Billing" section of my app. By pressing the "Send test notification", I correctly receive the notification on my server. However, when a customer really buys an "In-app" product, I don't receive any notification at all.

Someone has any idea why?

Comment: I'm seeing the same with license testers in my internal track app.